# How to sum up the cursor value and store the value in another select statement in the same procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, procedure

I have two tables, one is general table and another is `loan` table.

`General` table includes `id` and `name` and `id` is not repeating.

`Loan` table includes `id` and `loan amount`. In `loan` table, the `id` may be repeating as one customer can have multiple loans.

Idea is to create a procedure which will join this both the table on the basis of `id` and display the final table with `id`, `name` and sum of all loans for that particular `id` (must sum up the value of common `id`'s and store in single column) with the help of cursor.

Can only use procedure and cursor.

If it can be solved without cursor, then please provide the alternate solution.

I am using below query for the same, but unfortunately the end result displays the id multiple times:

```
SELECT
A.bpm_referenceno,
CASE WHEN B.loanbookingbranch='--Select--' or B.loanbookingbranch='null' THEN '' ELSE B.loanbookingbranch END,
CASE WHEN A.branch='' OR A.branch IS NULL OR A.branch='null' THEN '' ELSE A.branch END,
'',
CASE WHEN A.originator='' OR A.originator IS NULL OR A.originator='null' THEN '' ELSE A.originator END,
A.cif_id,
CASE WHEN D.callexecutiondate='' OR D.callexecutiondate IS NULL OR D.callexecutiondate ='null' THEN '' ELSE CASE WHEN D.calldescription='MG Contract Creation' AND D.callstatus='SUCCESS' THEN D.callexecutiondate END END,
CASE WHEN A.originationdate IS NULL THEN '' ELSE A.originationdate END,
CASE WHEN A.request_type='' OR A.request_type IS NULL OR A.request_type='null' THEN '' ELSE A.request_type END,
CASE WHEN a.loan_subtype='' OR a.loan_subtype IS NULL OR a.loan_subtype='null' THEN '' ELSE a.loan_subtype END,
CASE WHEN E.loanamounttxndetails IS NULL OR E.loanamounttxndetails ='null' OR E.loanamounttxndetails='' THEN '0' ELSE e.loanamounttxndetails END,
CASE WHEN E.customerdbrtxndetails IS NULL OR E.customerdbrtxndetails ='null' OR E.customerdbrtxndetails='' THEN '0.00' ELSE E.customerdbrtxndetails END,
'stlment count',
'loan os',
--Here I am inserting the query--
(SELECT
isnull(ab.mycount,0)
FROM
bm_rlos_exttable aa
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT bpm_referenceno,count(bpm_referenceno) mycount FROM
BM_RLOS_ExistingBMLiabilitiesGrid GROUP BY bpm_referenceno) ab ON aa.bpm_referenceno = ab.bpm_referenceno),
CASE WHEN G.isselected='true' THEN G.insuranceType ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN E.loantenortxndetails IS NULL OR E.loantenortxndetails='' OR E.loantenortxndetails='null' THEN '' ELSE E.loantenortxndetails END,
CASE WHEN E.interestratetxndetails IS NULL OR E.interestratetxndetails='' OR E.interestratetxndetails='null' THEN '' ELSE E.interestratetxndetails END,
'CHARGE1',
'CHARGE2',
CASE WHEN D.calldescription='MG Contract Creation' AND D.callstatus='SUCCESS' THEN D.callreferenceid ELSE '' END,
'rco',
'tat'

FROM
BM_RLOS_EXTTABLE A WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_BasicLoanDetailsForm B WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = B.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_DisbursementCallsGrid D WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = D.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_CheckFinalEligibilityForm E WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = E.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_ExistingBMLiabilitiesGrid F WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = F.bpm_referenceno 
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_InsuranceProductSelectionGrid G WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = G.bpm_referenceno 
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_ChargeAndFeeDetailsForm H WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = H.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm I WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = I.bpm_referenceno 
INNER JOIN wfcurrentroutelogtable J WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = J.ProcessInstanceId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.name,
b.mysum
FROM
General_Table a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select bpm_id, SUM(outstandingamount) mysum 
                 from loan_table group by bpm_id) b
ON a.id = b.bpm_id
```

Edit: subquery changed ( based on your join clause i assumed your id field in the loan_table was bpm_id)

Edit2:
Note i moved your nested query into a new LEFT JOIN in order to make this work.
You cannot use nested query in a select statement if it returns more then 1 record

```
SELECT
A.bpm_referenceno,
CASE WHEN B.loanbookingbranch='--Select--' or B.loanbookingbranch='null' THEN '' ELSE B.loanbookingbranch END,
CASE WHEN A.branch='' OR A.branch IS NULL OR A.branch='null' THEN '' ELSE A.branch END,
'',
CASE WHEN A.originator='' OR A.originator IS NULL OR A.originator='null' THEN '' ELSE A.originator END,
A.cif_id,
CASE WHEN D.callexecutiondate='' OR D.callexecutiondate IS NULL OR D.callexecutiondate ='null' THEN '' ELSE CASE WHEN D.calldescription='MG Contract Creation' AND D.callstatus='SUCCESS' THEN D.callexecutiondate END END,
CASE WHEN A.originationdate IS NULL THEN '' ELSE A.originationdate END,
CASE WHEN A.request_type='' OR A.request_type IS NULL OR A.request_type='null' THEN '' ELSE A.request_type END,
CASE WHEN a.loan_subtype='' OR a.loan_subtype IS NULL OR a.loan_subtype='null' THEN '' ELSE a.loan_subtype END,
CASE WHEN E.loanamounttxndetails IS NULL OR E.loanamounttxndetails ='null' OR E.loanamounttxndetails='' THEN '0' ELSE e.loanamounttxndetails END,
CASE WHEN E.customerdbrtxndetails IS NULL OR E.customerdbrtxndetails ='null' OR E.customerdbrtxndetails='' THEN '0.00' ELSE E.customerdbrtxndetails END,
'stlment count',
'loan os',
--Here I am inserting the query--
mycount,
CASE WHEN G.isselected='true' THEN G.insuranceType ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN E.loantenortxndetails IS NULL OR E.loantenortxndetails='' OR E.loantenortxndetails='null' THEN '' ELSE E.loantenortxndetails END,
CASE WHEN E.interestratetxndetails IS NULL OR E.interestratetxndetails='' OR E.interestratetxndetails='null' THEN '' ELSE E.interestratetxndetails END,
'CHARGE1',
'CHARGE2',
CASE WHEN D.calldescription='MG Contract Creation' AND D.callstatus='SUCCESS' THEN D.callreferenceid ELSE '' END,
'rco',
'tat'
FROM
BM_RLOS_EXTTABLE A WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_BasicLoanDetailsForm B WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = B.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_DisbursementCallsGrid D WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = D.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_CheckFinalEligibilityForm E WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = E.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_ExistingBMLiabilitiesGrid F WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = F.bpm_referenceno 
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_InsuranceProductSelectionGrid G WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = G.bpm_referenceno 
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_ChargeAndFeeDetailsForm H WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = H.bpm_referenceno
INNER JOIN BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm I WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = I.bpm_referenceno 
INNER JOIN wfcurrentroutelogtable J WITH (NOLOCK)
ON A.bpm_referenceno = J.ProcessInstanceId
left join
(SELECT bpm_referenceno,count(bpm_referenceno) mycount FROM
BM_RLOS_ExistingBMLiabilitiesGrid GROUP BY bpm_referenceno) ab ON ab.bpm_referenceno = a.bpm_referenceno)
```

Comment: Thanks man. You saved my day. It was exactly I was searching for.

Comment: You're welcome. Please check and accept answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: How can I use the above query as a nested query of any Select statement. I am trying to achieve this but getting an error  'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. Severity 16'

Comment: pls provide the code (you can edit your main post) you are trying to run and ill do my best ;)

Note: you can only accept 1 answer so if Michael's one solved your problem so accept his one.

Comment: I have replaced the code with my original code. Kindly check it. Kindly check the line -- Here I am inserting the query --. I want your query to be run at that point of code.

Comment: I tried the above approach. The query is taking too much of time in processing.

Comment: performance issues is something you have to face with, when you need aggregate functions (sum, count etc.). 
We cant help you on this without knowledge about your table structures such as field data type, length or table indexes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cursor at all! It's inefficient. This can be done simply by `JOIN`ing and `GROUP`ing. Try this query:

```
select g.id, l.totalLoan from GeneralTable [g]
join (
    select id, sum(loan) [totalLoan] from LoanTable
    group by id
) [l] on [g].id = [l].id
```

Comment: I tried the same approach, but again the in the end table, the id is repeating. I require id must not repeat and the loan amount must be summed up.

Comment: But how to use this query as a nested query?

Comment: @MDKAMRANAzam `select * from (` the query goes here `) [a]`

Comment: I am trying the same but getting an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. Severity 16"

Comment: Because you are using in a column list... You want to insert table into every row? Do you even know what are you trying to do?